# PHP regex +(plus) metacharacter

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of either a capital `E` or lowercase `e` with an *:

`echo preg_replace( "/[eE]+/", "*", "eeEE" );`

I expected the result to be: `****` since there are four characters in the `subject` of `preg_replace()`.

Current output is `*`.

Why is this not working as expected; what am I missing? Clearly I don't understand something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, just `str_ireplace("e","*","eeEE");` will do.

However, your misunderstanding is that your regex says "replace one *or more* Es, ***as many as possible*** with a single `*`". You do not need a `+` here, as you are replacing a single character with another single character.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the pure regex pattern if I did not use sophisticated functions as the one above, if any?

Comment: `/e/i` would be the simple regex.